# MSSQL Query with boolean return value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a mySQL query like

```
SELECT configs.*, (settings.defaultConfig=configs.id) AS isDefault FROM configs, settings
```

where settings is a table with only a single row, and settings.defaultConfig and configs.id are both pure integer columns, not allowing a NULL value.

Now I am searching for an mssql query doing the same: returning whether the config at hand is the defaultConfig or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT configs.*, 
    (case when settings.defaultConfig is null then 0 else 1 end) AS isDefault 
FROM configs left join settings on settings.defaultConfig=configs.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statment:

```
CASE configs.id WHEN settings.defaultConfig THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isDefault
```

There is no `boolean` data type in MSSQL, the closest would be `bit`.